# IE9 address bar disappears / not selectable

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9

A Win7 Professional desktop PC with IE9 installed keeps losing the address bar from IE9.

If we go to the View menu, there is no address bar to select to display:
[image]

I tried doing "REGSVR32 /i BROWSEUI.DLL" but receive the error:
[image]

Comment: Try the **Internet Explorer (No Add-ons)** shortcut from the Start Menu and see if the problem occurs. If not, one of the toolbars or other add-ons is to blame.

Comment: Reinstall Internet Explorer

Comment: I reinstalled IE and the problem was resolved initially, but reoccurred a day later.

Comment: Unfortunately No Add-ons results in the same symptom - no address bar, and no ability to select it in Toolbars.

Comment: the same problem occurs to me today...just upgrade from ie8 to ie9, no improvement:( Also runned the no add-ons version, doesn't work either:(

Comment: FYI, on another machine without this problem, the address bar is non-selectable, there are only menu/favorites/command/status bar in the menu.

Answer (score 1):

try to run the following command and see if the adddress bar comes back (it did on my machine):

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbars\Restrictions" /v "NoNavBar" /t REG_DWORD /d "0" /f
```